# session using asp.net and passing values

Tags: asp.net

I want to know that how to use session in asp.net for that I use the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string academics = "academics";
    Session["header_value"] = academics;
}
```

then I want to use that value in following code

```
<a href="academics.aspx">
     <%if("header_value"=="academics")
     {%>
          <div id="academics" class="pri-nav active"></div>
     <%}else{%>
          <div id="academics" class="pri-nav"></div>
     <%}%></a>
```

I also want to know that is there any other way to pass value to .cs other than session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protected or public variables can be accessed on the page.

```
protected string ActiveNav = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ActiveNav = "academics";
}
```

and

```
   <a href="academics.aspx">
       <div id="academics" class="pri-nav <%= ActiveNav=="academics"? "active" :"" %> "></div>
   </a>
```

Comment: it gives error "The name 'ActiveNav' does not exist in the current context" i write                                                                  protected string ActiveNav = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ActiveNav = "academics";
}
in academics.cs and "<a href="academics.aspx">
       <div id="academics" class="pri-nav <%= ActiveNav=="academics"? "active" :"" %> "></div>
   </a>
"         in master file

Comment: If you want to do navigation the right way do this: Make a .sitemap and use a SiteMapDataSource to get the current url based on the sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you do in your code-behind:

```
... <%if(Session["header_value"] == "academics") { ...
```

Or more succinctly:

```
<a href="academics.aspx">
    <div id="academics"
         class="pri-nav <%=Session["header_value"] == "academics" ? "active" : ""%>"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: but i want to use css class dynamically ...how

Comment: i had this code in academic.cs file                             protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)                 { HeaderText = "academics"; }                                                                    but i want to use in file college.aspx which is master file then how can i?

Answer (score 0):

in aspx file :

```
<%if(get_session()=="academics")
{%>
     <div id="academics" class="pri-nav active"></div>
<%}else{%>
     <div id="academics" class="pri-nav"></div>
<%}%>
```

in aspx.cs file :

```
public String get_session() 
{
    string academics = "academics";
    Session["header_value"] = academics;

    return academics;
}
```